# The maxLength attribute in EditText doesn't work as expected via xml and java

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, android-input-filter

Maybe this is already answered but I can't find it on SO.

I have a very simple requirement: Restrict the length of characters in an EditText.

I use the `maxLength` tag in xml for this.
The strange thing is, if the length of the inputted text exceeds the specified limit, the text can't be deleted by pressing backspace via soft keyboard. The inputted text remains in the EditText field. After closing and reopening the soft keayboard, the text becomes "deleteable".

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:hint="text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding this layout is enough to get the described behaviour.

I added an InputFilter to see what's going on here. The result as described will be the same without the InputFilter!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source,
                int start,
                int end,
                Spanned dest,
                int dstart,
                int dend) {

            if (source != null) {
                Log.v("edit","source = " + source.toString());
                Log.v("edit","start = " + start);
                Log.v("edit","end = " + end);
            }
            if (dest != null) { 
                Log.v("edit","dest= " + dest.toString());
                Log.v("edit","dstart = " + dstart);
                Log.v("edit","dend = " + dend);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    InputFilter[] oldFilters = et.getFilters();
    InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[oldFilters.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(oldFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, oldFilters.length);
    newFilters[oldFilters.length] = filter;
    et.setFilters(newFilters);
}
```

While logging I can see that `source` will remain the same, if the `maxLength` is exceeded, but the Spanned `dest` changes the way it should, deleting the chars of text by pressing backspace.

Now what is going on here? Is this a bug or really the default behaviour. Because if a User types his text and the limit is exceeded, he has no chance for correction.

Edit:

The suggested way by Sandeep Kumar using Java code to set the maxLength leads to the same result.

```
 et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5)});
```

BTW, I'm using Android API 4.4.2 and SDK 23.0.2.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same problem and I came here looking for answers. Glad it's not just me.

Comment: @StayFrosty It's still unresolved. Major fact is that i can't put any time in it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView editEntryView = new TextView(...);
InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8);
editEntryView.setFilters(filterArray);
```

Comment: This produces the same result. The chars in the EditText remain the same by pressing backspace, if the maxLength exceeds.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to use Length restricting textwatcher as below and use textNoSuggestions as inputType

```
public class LengthTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    String prevVal = "";
    int length;
    public LengthTextWatcher(int l) {
        length = l;
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s != null && s.length() > 0) {
            if(s.length() > length) {
                s.clear();
                s.insert(0, prevVal);
            }
            prevVal = s.toString();
        }
    }
}

...
```

Sample way to apply textWatcher

```
mFirstNameET.addTextChangedListener(new LengthTextWatcher(35));
```

And

```
 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```